# What's the best approach for developing a BlackBerry web application (WebWorks Application)

Tags: c#, java, web-applications, blackberry, webforms

I'm already a Junior asp.net/c# developer and I know that java is pretty similar to C#.

I've considered using two methods:

- the Java toolkit (which is the native language of the BB's OS so I
  thought it would be more powerful)
- the Visual studio (asp.net) toolkit (which is the language and the
  platform I already know and practiced
  before)

so which one of those are the best approach?
what are the advantages/disadvantages for every approach?
do you suggest other solutions for developing a blackberry version of my asp.net website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same choice, and from what I see, it doesn't matter.  You're developing web pages with additional API's interfaces that allow the WebKit browser to take advantage of the Blackberry API's.

It doesn't look like WebWorks applications run either Java OR .NET code.  Instead, WebWorks apps are made up of HTML, css, and javascript.

However, if you're planning on doing standard Blackberry apps, you'll want to go with Java. This will also help to prepare you for developing on the Android platform.  Java isn't going away any time soon, and with the rise in popularity of the Android platform, I think that the demand for Java development is going to be on the rise, compared to .NET.  (I say this as someone who LOVES .NET and does NOT want to re-learn Java, but is doing so to ensure that I'll be able to compete in the job market.)

Comment: Well David, your answer is pretty helpful .. well java and it's web application framework download is so confusing to me! >> SE EE ME EF!!! .. anyway thank you =) Marked as answer but I hope you'd send me some resources (books, blogs, ..) to get me started as it's my first time using java at all!

Comment: There are plenty of resources for learning Java.  The problem is that many of them are for pure beginners, and the rest cover advanced tools, assuming that you've got the intermediate experience.  When you get past the point of learning the language basics, and start wondering "Where do I go next", I'd recommend one book that's been helpful to me as it addresses this gap:  Wrox Press's Professional Java JDK 6 Edition (ISBN 978-0-471-77710-6).  It it sthe only resource I've found that bridges the gap and introduces you (gently) to common tools and best practices.